# Mount RW access to EFI partition windows 10

Tags: windows-10, efi

How to get RW access to the EFI partition in Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 1809?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working way to gain RW access to EFI partition in windows 10:
Download explorer https://explorerplusplus.com/.

Start cmd.exe with administrative privileges.

```
dispart
select disk 0
select vol 2 (# EFI partition)
assign
exit
explorer++.exe
```

Done.

Comment: Use `mountvol /s S:` to do the same thing diskpart does in one command.